# openssl enc -base64 -d does not decode strings after a certain length

Tags: bash, encoding, openssl

I have a simple bash script that does encoding / decoding for strings using base64. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "encode or decode ?"
read input

if [ "$input" == "encode" ]
then

echo Please, enter your secret message 
read message
echo "The cipher representing your message is"
echo -n $message | openssl enc -base64


else

echo "Please enter your cipher"
read cipher
echo "Your secret message is"
echo  $cipher | openssl enc -base64 -d
echo ""


fi
```

The script works fine, as long as the length of the string being encoded is 49 characters at max. Strings longer than 49 characters can not be decoded correctly. Any idea what might be wrong in my script?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`openssl enc -base64` is inserting a carriage return after 64 characters of encoded string. This actually happens about the 49th character of string to be encoded.

To avoid this line break in the encoded string, use option `-A` in both `openssl` commands to encode or decode the whole string at once:

```
echo -n $message | openssl enc -base64 -A
```

and

```
echo  $cipher | openssl enc -base64 -d -A
```

This looks to be specific to `openssl`. If you would use `base64` executable from the coreutils package, this would work as well.

Comment: _As a side note:_ we can also use a short form which is without `enc` part: `openssl base64`.